# Setting default UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark in table from Core Data, THEN allowing new selection to be captured

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

I have a `SoundTableViewController` with 3 static rows that indicated sound selection options.  I want to load a selected / default `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` on the row with the corresponding name/string value from an object in Core Data.  Not too difficult.  However, once the checkmark has been successfully added, I want to allow the user the ability to select and deselect any of the other sounds and have the checkmark added / removed.  Once the user has made their final selection, I want to add / update the selected sound to the corresponding object in Core Data and save.  In addition, I want to have this selection persist should the user navigate away from the `SoundTableViewController` and return.

I'm able to get the 'checking and unchecking' of a row to work using a marker for the indexPath in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  I'm able to get the default selection to be 'checked' when loading property in Core Data.  However, I'm not sure how to have BOTH of these things occur at the same time.

Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` methods.

**`cellForRowAtIndexPath`**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"sound";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 

if(cell == nil )
{
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Getting file name from path for title of cell
NSString *fileName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
fileName = [[fileName lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
cell.textLabel.text = fileName;
NSLog(@"FILENAME HAS A VALUE OF:   %@", fileName);

if ([indexPath compare:self.lastIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
    {

        //If sound has been selected previously, set sound selection
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:self.selectedSound])
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }

        //if no sound has been selected previously, set 'Bells' as default sound
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Bells"])
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
    }
else
    {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }    

//The following is the original code to 'check and uncheck' rows
/*
if ([indexPath compare:self.lastIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
*/

return cell;
}
```

**`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I'm assuming the logic I need should all go into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  However, perhaps the best approach is to have the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do the new selection and saving to Core Data?

Again, I want to:

1. Load a checkmark on the selected / default row at start
2. Allow user to select any sound from table and have a checkmark for current
   selected row only
3. Save selected row to current object from Core Data upon final selection

Any insights or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are setting the cell text even before the cell is created.

```
// Getting file name from path for title of cell
NSString *fileName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
fileName = [[fileName lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
cell.textLabel.text = fileName;
NSLog(@"FILENAME HAS A VALUE OF:   %@", fileName);


if(cell == nil )
{
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

I think your first cell may not have any text in it? Does it? Also how are you initializing self.lastIndexPath and self.selectedSound when the view first appears?

Comment: Cell was created prior, but I moved the code to eliminate confusion.  All cells created without problem.  First cell is fine.  `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;` is synthesized and `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedSound;` is as well.  `self.selectedSound = self.soundTransferString;` sets my selected sound string from my object in Core Data.